# 入力を受け付けなくなったがSSHログインはできるMacを再起動なしに救いたい

Tags: macos

まれに、Macがフリーズしてマウスもキーボードも受け付けなくなることがあります。SSHでログインしてkillしたりはできるのですが、結局再起動しないと直りません。最悪の場合、電源ボタンでの強制終了しか受け付けてくれません。

今し方起きたフリーズだと、以下を試してもダメでした。

- `top -o -cpu` で見つけた忙しそうなプロセスを `kill`
- `sudo killall Finder`: 効果なし
- `sudo killall -HUP WindowServer`: ログアウトされたが、入力は受け付けないまま

結局 `sudo shutdown -r now` で再起動しました。 (これも途中でフリーズすることがある。)

OS の外部入力部分だけをリセットしたりできないのでしょうか。

環境: Mac OS X 10.10.1 / MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

Comment: フリーズが発生するのは、使用中ですか？ それともスリープ後などプロセス復帰が絡むタイミングでしょうか？

Comment: @mutuki 使用中です。トラックパッドでマウスカーソルを動かそうとした瞬間が多いような気もします

Comment: ちょっとアイソレーションしたほうが良さそうですね。別アカウントを作って（もしくはゲストアカウントを有効にして）そちらでログインして操作するとどうでしょう？
改善するなら疑うべきプロセスはユーザーがオーナーのものに絞れると思います。

Comment: @mutuki なるほど。個人設定に依存しないような作業をする時はゲストアカウントでやるようにしてみます。

Comment: 同じ症状がこちらでも再現しました。OSのバージョンは10.10ですか?

Comment: @mutuki そうです。私の方はそれ以来再現してないです

Answer (score 8):

loginwindow プロセスを kill してみてはどうでしょうか。

```
sudo killall loginwindow
```

この場合、ログアウトして、WindowServer プロセスも終了します。
その後、launchd が loginwindow プロセスを上げ直すはずです。

ちなみに loginwindow が起動し直すのは /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.loginwindow.plist に

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```

の記載があるためです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。次回フリーズしたら試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

（コメントできないので、こちらですいません）

原因が違うかもしれませんが、私の環境でも11月21日に OSX 10.10.1 の際に起きています。
理由は内部キーボードおよび内部トラックパッドが切断されたというものでした。
切断されたことがわかったのは[hardwaregrowler](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/hardwaregrowler/id475260933?mt=12)を入れていたおかげです。

その際はBTキーボードとBTトラックパッドを接続して、セーフブートで事なきを得たのですが、当然予めペアリング済みであることが必要です。
こちらの環境ではセーフブート後は起きていないので、もしかしたら違うかもしれませんが、参考迄に。